# Can ShellExecute run in active session?

Tags: c++, sessionid, shellexecute

I have a command  that i need run by cmd.exe when something happens in my program. Let's say the command is "calc.exe". When i use ShellExecute:

```
HWND win = GetActiveWindow();
ShellExecute(win,L"open",L"calc.exe",L"",L"", SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

The calc.exe process starts in session 0 so i cannot see it. Is there any way to set it to start in the active users window? I don't want to use CreateProcess as I have been having privilege issues with it

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by "session"?

Comment: ive edited the qustion. but basically i could see from task manager thatthe calc.exe process is running in session 0(so cant see it). i want it to run in the active users window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `ShellExecute` cannot run a program in another session. You'll need to use `CreateProcessAsUser`. There are numerous questions on here that discuss how to do this.

Comment: i feared someone would say that. Cheers